Boolean operation makes the cutting object into wireframe
I'm trying to make a Boolean cut, from object A into object B. Both Meshes have enough loop cuts.
When I add the Boolean operation difference from object A into object B, The cutting object turns into a wireframe.
But when I perform the same procedure from object B (making it the cutting object) into object A, the Boolean works.
Why am I doing incorrect, and Object A cannot be used to Make a Boolean into Object B?


Try setting the modifier's Solver to Fast instead of Exact. And apart from that, select all in Edit Mode on both meshes and hit X > Limited Dissolve to get rid of all this unnecessary geometry. And by the way, the BoolTool does not turn the cutting object into a wireframe, but sets it to be displayed as Bounds (which is why both only show a bounding box, even though the actual shape is different). The tool does that so that the cutting object is not obstructing the view on the result, as the lower example where the cut worked shows.
